# Sequentially enabling fieldsets in a form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I know how to enable next `fieldset` in a sequence when fieldsets have `id` attributes:

```js
function enableFieldset(element) {
  document.getElementById(element).disabled = false;
}
```

```html
<fieldset id="foo" onchange="enableFieldset('bar', event)">
<label><input type="radio" name="foo">Apples</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="foo">Oranges</label>
</fieldset>

<fieldset id="bar" disabled>
<label><input type="radio" name="bar">Bus</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="bar">Airplane</label>
</fieldset>

…
```

I would like to enable the next sibling `fieldset` in a multi-step form, that has no set `id` (by using `.nextElementSibling` or similar), after input is checked in the current `fieldset`. I would also like to separate JavaScript from HTML code (with `addEventListener`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach the `change` event listener to all the fieldsets by selecting them using `document.querySelectorAll`. This will separate the JS code from HTML.

In the event handler, you can get the next sibling, which is disabled, and enable it. Use `nextElementSibling` for that.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('fieldset').forEach(fs => {
  fs.addEventListener('change', function() {
    var next = this.nextElementSibling;
    
    while (next && !next.disabled) {
      next = next.nextElementSibling;
    }
    
    if (next) {
      next.disabled = false;
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<fieldset id="foo">
  <label><input type="radio" name="foo">Apples</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="foo">Oranges</label>
</fieldset>

<fieldset id="bar" disabled>
  <label><input type="radio" name="bar">Bus</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="bar">Airplane</label>
</fieldset>

<fieldset id="bar" disabled>
  <label><input type="radio" name="x">Bus1</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="x">Airplane1</label>
</fieldset>

<fieldset id="bar" disabled>
  <label><input type="radio" name="y">Bus2</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="y">Airplane2</label>
</fieldset>
```